# use wget to get script links of a website

Tags: wget, penetration-testing

I've been using wget spider to collect all of a website's links, but it will not return the paths to scripts. Is there any way to do this? My current wget request:

```
    wget --spider --recursive --no-verbose --output-file=wget.txt https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-p` or `--page-requisites` option. That will download all the extra assets.

Comment: Will that download the files, or just their links?

Comment: I don't want the files, just links

Comment: @SanicRider When you use the `--spider` option it won't download the JS/CSS/etc. It just lists them out.